# Adding Methods To Windows Form?

Tags: c#

I have 2 windows Forms, a parent and a child. The parent is the main form. The child is a dialog where the user can edit their details.

When a button is clicked on the parent form, it loads the child form. Like so:

```
private void add_account_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.account_add_edit = new Form2();
     account_add_edit.test();
     account_add_edit.ShowDialog();
}
```

As you can see I've created a new form, tried to call a function from the new form, and then showed the form. The problem is the method from the form is not being called. I am getting an error on the IDE that says Windows.Forms.Form does not contain a method test.

I've created the method in the child form:

```
public static string test(string val)
{
    this.username = val;
}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, at least the method should not be static, because: 1 - you are trying to access instance field from it; 2 - you are trying to call it on instance of Form2.

Comment: You're not passing the requisite `string` parameter to it when you call it either.

Comment: Sorry jonsca, I typed it out and forgot to pass the string.

Answer (score 2):

your method is defined as static , so its not posiible to call it on an instace. 
you should eaither not make it static, or call it from as static:

```
Form2.test();
```

Comment: Ah, fixed. I was create a class of type Form and not of type Form2. Form2 is the form class for the child (poor naming I know). Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
   Form2.test();
```

`static` members are associated directly to the *class* not to its *instances*. Than means if you need to access a `static` member you have to access it using it is container *type*.

More than that, you can not access *normal* members from `static` ones. You can only access `static`members from their peers.

**You cannot do the following inside a `static` method:**

```
this.Member ...
```